# Set users to use bluetooth

Tags: ios, iphone, core-bluetooth

How can I set the users to centrals/peripherals so that they can get data from each other while logged in? Would I have to set up a custom UUID service?

My app uses photos. When a user taps a photo I want it to take a picture of the user that posted the photo. I'd like to use snapStillImage from the AVFoundation framework. If you have any bluetooth experience, or awesome tutorials to reference; let's talk.

I want to trigger this method when a user taps another users photo using some type of custom bluetooth peripheral service

```
-(void)snapStillImage //this is being called on did load
{
dispatch_async([self sessionQueue], ^{
    // Update the orientation on the still image output video connection before capturing.
    [[[self stillImageOutput] connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] setVideoOrientation:[[(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[[self previewView] layer] connection] videoOrientation]];
    // Flash set to Auto for Still Capture
    [ViewController5 setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeAuto forDevice:[[self videoDeviceInput] device]];
    // Capture a still image.
    [[self stillImageOutput] captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:[[self stillImageOutput] connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
        if (imageDataSampleBuffer)
        {
            NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];

            photo.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
            [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[photo.image CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[photo.image imageOrientation] completionBlock:nil];
            [self uploadPhoto];
}
    }];
});
}
```

***current code triggered when a photo is tapped***

```
-(void)didSelectPhoto:(PhotoView*)sender {
//photo selected - show it full screen
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowPhoto" sender:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag]];
}
//face value zap method
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([@"ShowPhoto" compare: segue.identifier]==NSOrderedSame) {
    StreamPhotoScreen* streamPhotoScreen = segue.destinationViewController;
    streamPhotoScreen.IdPhoto = sender;
}
}
```

Comment: I suppose you doesn't make yourself clear. I have implemented an app using the **bluetooth** feature based on `core-bluetooth`. Please describe your question in detail.

Comment: Ok http://www.raywenderlich.com/13511/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-12 this app lets users login and take and upload photos. Users can browse photos in a UIScrollView. When a photo is tapped, it segues to a new view controller to show the image in full screen. How can we make it so that when an image is tapped, the user who uploaded the image's device takes a picture and shows it to the user who triggered the tap using bluetooth? I think its possible if we set peripherals/services/characteristics with the snapStillImage method, right?

Comment: So you're not going anymore for Multipeer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076163/take-pictures-on-other-ios-devices-using-bluetooth ?

Comment: No: bluetooth functionality comes first. Also the MPF is more location based. For me that can be added later

Comment: Bluetooth Low Energy with its effective bandwidth of 0.27 Mbit/s is not the best choice for sending photos (which can have several megabytes). Also, Multipeer Connectivity uses Bluetooth under the hood and does all the boring tasks like discovery, setting up centrals / peripherals for you. Why do you want to use Bluetooth for that? And what do you mean by *MPF is more location based*? It has more or less the same range as Bluetooth.

Comment: you're probably right. do you have any code? i really want to get this up and running ha.

Comment: Would I be able to add the desired feature without changing the whole set up of the app?